# Uninstall kodi on UBUNTU 14

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, kodi

I would like to uninstall KODI on my UBUNTU 14 and since i am a newbie on Linux and open source world, I don't really know what to do.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Lida

Comment: How was it installed in the first place?

Comment: My pro sister helped me.  I just learnt how to install and haven't learnt anything about uninstallation yet.

Comment: if you don't know how it was installed, then we can't give accurate guidance because it could have been installed one of fifty ways (and we would be guessing at best how it was installed).  Time to ask your sister to give details about how it was installed in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

see if this helps:

scrolls down for unistalling instructions.

http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux

> **1.6 Uninstalling**
>
> If you need to remove and purge an application and finally removing/purging also the application configurations files, do so by using the following commands:
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get remove kodi*`
>
> `sudo apt-get purge kodi*`
>
> Then remove the settings folder to remove all settings and library data. This will not delete any videos or music, but just the settings and library data itself:
>
> `rm -r ~/.kodi/`
>
> or
>
> `rm -r ~/.xbmc/`
>
> for older versions before 14.0

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. Appreciate it. Kodi was causing High System Tempreture on my Dell/Ubuntu. I thought may be its a good idea to uninstall it.  Thanks!

Comment: you're most welcome. I do have Kodi install on my system (which is down at the moment), however I have not experienced any issues, so far.

Comment: oops posted the comment sooner than expected ... if your system is old it might have to do with the system, I have a dell laptop and I know on that specific model (Latitude E6400 made in 2009) they had a recall due to heating issues. I'd suggest follow the instruction on installing Kodi from the link again and see if you experience the same problem as before.

Comment: Thanks. Its been 2 months that i purchased this new laptop. I installed kodi on another latop that i had at home. So i'm good now. I just did not want any harm on my new laptop since i am working with it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Got it! stream away and enjoy. Also, if you're using Ubuntu 14, consider upgrading it to a later version since it's getting closer to it's end of life.

Comment: @MarkKirby sorry about that, didn't know how to do it right inside the > sign

Comment: @MarkYisri Ah, OK, in that case use backticks ` to make code with a quote eg: `code`

Comment: @Hooman, it's recommended to do `purge` instead of `remove`, since `purge` includes `remove`. As you have it, I think that `remove` will remove the packages, keeping around the configuration files, and `purge` will think the packages are already removed, so it won't remove the configuration files.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex While first part of your statement is correct, I doubt the second part is. `purge` does not depend on remove, so while `remove` removes all the packages, `purge` would first look for packages which don't exist anymore and then looks for configurations and removes them. Some actually do use 'apt-get remove --purge packagename'. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Hooman I've tested it out with the `angband` package, and it looks like you're correct about the second part.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Cheers!